# iOS 8 Mac OS X Simulators, clicking on anchor tags with href=mailto do not populate the Mail App composer

Tags: macos, ios8, ios-simulator, anchor, mailto

This it not an issue on real iOS devices, only in iOS simulator devices.

In iOS 8 simulator devices, clicking on a anchor tag that have `<a href="mailto:me@example.com">` opens the Mail App but does not populate the `to` field in composer.

After further testing, I found that ONLY the `subject` fields gets populated for some reason, but not the others `mailto:?to=me@example.com&subject=mysubject&body=mybody`

- **Tested Simulated devices:** iPhone 5/5s/6/6+, iPad air, iPad mini, I gave up.
- **Firmware:** iOS 8.0.x and iOS 8.1, so you need xcode 6.1
- **Test Page:** http://jsbin.com/roxage/2/ this test page have **a lot of combinations**, as I tried many [RFC 2368](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt)-valid formats, and it looks Apple's implementation of Mail App [claims](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference.pdf#page=6) to be compatible.

I think I tried everything I know, does anyone have a workaround?

There was a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139096/mail-composer-bug-in-ios-8) - but it's tagged as Objective C question and it was down voted for using xcode6-beta a month ago, i presume.

Mine is much simpler, the anchor tags on **any HTML page** with mailto simply don't work as expected in iOS 8 Simulator. It's obviously a bug in the Mail App when it's in a virtual machine, but I am looking to see if someone found a workaround somehow. I already filed a bug at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com) but there is no publicly accessible URL to share here.

**I tested iOS 7.1 Simulators on many devices, and they all work fine.**

Comment: File a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: I already did, mentioned that in the last paragraph. Anyways, Apple replied at me saying that it's duplicate bug that they know about and they closed mine. But i have to way to track that other bug since their bug tracker is not publicly accessible, and users can only see the bugs that they file.

Comment: You can always ask for updates and ADC will respond back.  What was your radar number?  I'm curious and want to look it up.

Comment: The one I filed, 18782267, the duplicate is 18393623